# What is the difference between "bug in requirements" and "change request"

Tags: requirements

Recently I've been assigned a bug to fix, which from my point of view, was actually a change request. After some investigation it turned out that this bug was caused by a defect in business requirements, but it was still considered as a bug.

I often see change requests being pushed forward masqueraded as bugs. I am just trying to figure out if there are any differences.

Comment: Are you asking for legal or technical advice? (I.e. is this a question of whether to bill the work fixing the changed requirement?) In any case, who wrote the business requirements? Your team? If so, was the bug caused by missing information that the client should have provided, or a mistake on your part?

Comment: We have 2 teams - developers and business analysts. Analysts produce business spec -> we implement it. Next step - testing - analysts might test and raise bugs in what we've implemented. IMHO anything that "changes" original requirements after they were implemented is a change request - even if it's a mistake in those original requirements. What I'm looking for some is arguments to prove me right or wrong. And even if I'm right - i still have to convince others.

Comment: And when Programmers.SE was created? http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "bug in requirements" means there was something wrong with how the functionality was originally designed.

A "change request" means that everything was defined correct, but the customer wants a piece of functionality changed/added.

Comment: That seems correct to me, but from developer's point of view they look very similar to me in case when bug in requirements was found after it was implemented. And at the same time - PM's have a habit to treat one from another in a different way: i.e. bugfix risks are usually lower then change request risks. So from my point of view there are 3 distinct things: 1) bugs in req.; 2) change requests and 3) development bugs. But usually they are categorized as either "BUG"s or "CR"s.

Answer (score 1):

It happens all the time.

We as developers generally get annoyed if we get our things thrown back at us as having bugs to fix where it wasn't our fault.

What to do depends on the situation and on the process. Unless you get your performance reviews damaged by those, just don't think of those much and implement those bugs/changes.

Comment: Its not only about performance reviews. That is change requests usually decrease stability, while bug fixes improve it - therefore risks connected to implementing change requests are higher.